# Анимация с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скажите, пожалуйста, почему при нажатии на ссылку блок подлетает плавно сверху, а при повторном нажатии он просто резко исчезает, а хочется, чтобы он также плавно улетел вверх.

```js
$('.klik').on('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
  $('#cd-login').toggleClass('is-visible');
  if($('#cd-login').hasClass('is-visible')){
    $('#cd-login').stop().css('display', 'block').animate({top: 100}, 3);
  }else{
    $('#cd-login').stop().animate({'top': '-100%'}, 3);
    $('#cd-login').queue(function() {
      $('#cd-login').css('display', 'none');
    });
  }

});
```

```css
#cd-login {
  display: none;
  top: -100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 130px);
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: auto;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: rgba(239, 236, 236, 0.52);
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#cd-login.is-visible{
    z-index: 3; 
}
.klik{
  padding:20px;
  background: #8FBB6D;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#0" class="klik">Нажми</a>
<div id="cd-login">
  Привет
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В **css**: `transition: top 0.3s ease-out;`

```js
$('.klik').on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#cd-login').toggleClass('is-visible');
  if($('#cd-login').hasClass('is-visible')){
    $('#cd-login').stop().show().animate({top: 100}, 3);
  }else{
    $('#cd-login').animate({top: -400}, 300, function(){$('#cd-login').hide();});
  }
});
```

```css
#cd-login {
  display: none;
  top: -100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 130px);
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: auto;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: rgba(239, 236, 236, 0.52);
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: top 0.3s ease-out;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#cd-login.is-visible{
    z-index: 3; 
}
.klik{
  padding:20px;
  background: #8FBB6D;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#0" class="klik">Нажми</a>
<div id="cd-login">
  Привет
</div>
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!:)

Answer (score 0):

$('#cd-login').css('display', 'none'); - блок прятать не нужно, так как вы прочите блок за экран.

```js
$('.klik').on('click', function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
  $('#cd-login').toggleClass('is-visible');
  if($('#cd-login').hasClass('is-visible')){
    $('#cd-login').stop().css('display', 'block').animate({top: 100}, 3);
  }else{
    $('#cd-login').stop().animate({'top': '-100%'}, 3);
  }

});
```

```css
#cd-login {
  display: none;
  top: -100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 130px);
  background: #eee;
  padding: 20px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 41px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  overflow: auto;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-color: rgba(239, 236, 236, 0.52);
  -moz-border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: top 0.3s;
  transition: top 0.3s;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
#cd-login.is-visible{
    z-index: 3; 
}
.klik{
  padding:20px;
  background: #8FBB6D;
  color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#0" class="klik">Нажми</a>
<div id="cd-login">
  Привет
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но мне нужно обратно установить `display: none;` так как в этом блоке у меня находится форма входа для сайта, если не ставить `display: none;` то постоянно на сайте пишет слева от `url` - "Не защищено" или по другому - "Подключение к сайту не защищено"